# Inkscape 1.0 not able to export files needed for svg package

Tags: svg, inkscape, export

After updating Inkscape for the 1.0 version the svg package invocation of inkscape leads to the following message in the log file:

> Package svg Info: Calling Inkscape on input line 19.
>   runsystem(inkscape -z -C --export-latex  --file="truss.svg"
>   --export-pdf="truss
>   _svg-tex.pdf" )...executed.
>
> Package svg Warning: The export with Inkscape failed for file (svg)
>   `truss.svg' (svg)                Troubleshooting: Please check in the
>   log file how (svg)                the invocation of Inkscape took
>   place and try to (svg)                execute it yourself in the
>   terminal on input line 19.

and the files "truss_svg-tex.pdf" and "truss_svg-tex.pdf_tex" are not created.
I tried to execute the command

> inkscape -z -C --export-latex  --file="truss.svg" --export-pdf="truss_svg-tex.pdf"

in the command prompt and the two files "truss_svg-tex.pdf" and "truss_svg-tex.pdf_tex" were not created and a strange message was issued: "OpAA". Of course, a workaround is to open Inkscape and do File->Save As->pdf and then choose the "Omit text in PDF and create LaTeX file" option. Finally "_svg-tex" has be added to name of both files created. However, this is very unpleasant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your "svg.sty" file (`/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/svg/svg.sty` for me), replace the lines

```
\newcommand*\svg@ink@cmd[2]{
  \svg@ink@exe\space-z\space\svg@ink@area\space%
  \ifx\svg@ink@dpi\relax\else--export-dpi=\svg@ink@dpi\space\fi%
  \if@svg@ink@latex--export-latex\space\fi%
  \svg@ink@opt\space%
  --file="#1.\svg@file@ext"\space%
  --export-\svg@ink@format="#2.\svg@ink@format"\space%
}
```

with

```
\newcommand*\svg@ink@cmd[2]{%
  \svg@ink@exe\space\svg@ink@area\space%
  \ifx\svg@ink@dpi\relax\else--export-dpi=\svg@ink@dpi\space\fi%
  \if@svg@ink@latex--export-latex\space\fi%
  \svg@ink@opt\space%
  "#1.\svg@file@ext"\space%
  --export-type="\svg@ink@format"\space%
  --export-filename="#2.\svg@ink@format"\space%
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rick, your solution works beautifully! I see that a change was incorporated yesterday (after I post this question) in the svg package to solve this problem.

Comment: I've opened an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/mrpiggi/svg/issues/38)